# Keep custom user role after order status is completed in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles, woocommerce-subscriptions

Here’s the situation: I initially set users that once they have completed a form, their user role is set to "Interviewed".

The problem arises when the subscription payment gets renewed (user role goes back to "Subscriber") or there's some temporary payment renewal issue (user role is set to "Customer").

I need the User's role to stay on "Interviewed" if the Order status is Completed.

So this is what I came up with:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'keep_role_interviewed' );
function keep_role_interviewed( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if ( $order->user_id > 0 ) {
         $user = new WP_User( $order->user_id );
         $user_data = array( 'ID' => $user->ID,'role' => 'Interviewed' );

         wp_update_user( $user_data );  
    }
}
```

But it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

Here I finally made it work.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_status_updated', 'keep_interviewed_role' );
function keep_interviewed_role( $subscription) {
    
    
    // Get the WC_Order Object from subscription
    $order = wc_get_order( $subscription->get_parent_id() );
    $order_status = $order->get_status();
    
    // Get an instance of the customer WP_User Object
    $user = $order->get_user();


        if( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) && !in_array('interviewed', $user->roles)
             && $order_status == ('completed')); {

             $user->set_role( 'interviewed' );
        }
}
```